# PHP: Does password_hash() check if the hash generated is unique? (Understanding!)

Tags: php, password-hash

Simple question because i did not find a really helping answer on google: Does the password_hash() function also check if there is already such a hash generated for instance in the userdata file? 
I basically get what the function is doing, but i am fairly new to php, so i was not really able to see if the password is checked for uniqueness.

Please be gentle on this noob question right here. I simply want to understand what i am using right there, and not only do it because my exercise sheet at university tells me so.

Comment: It's simply hashses the given password. Nothing more, nothing less. Not sure what you need a unique password for - it's the username or appropriate ID that should be unique by convention

Comment: How can the function know "where to look"? Anyway chances for collisions are very very low.

Comment: What's a userdata file? PHP functions (mostly) are stateless.

Comment: Well we have got a register normform at the moment, with a connected userdata.json file. I simply wanted to know if the function checks it or not. But well. Asking for theoretical knowledge is bad as it looks from the downvotes. And i always thought it would be better to understand stuff and not just use it.

Comment: Why is it important that a hash in unique?

Comment: Well i was just theoretically thinking about it. I mean couldnt it be somehow somwhere that two hashes would be identically generated? We need to save it in the userdata file, so i was just curious.

Comment: @Calimera, theoretical questions like this are not suitable for StackOverflow. Also, the one thing that is pretty good about PHP is the documentation. If the docs do not mention any of it, it is not in.

Comment: But i dont understand why? I mean there are people on here who have been working years with such functions, who definitely know their stuff really good. I was just wondering if it could be a safety problem, dont know whats so bad in thinking about it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Two reasons:

- the function will not know anything about "other" passwords.
- You don't want this. What will you do if you hit a duplicate? Tell the user? He will then know someone's password.

Answer (score 1):

The password_hash() function is designed in a way that duplicates are extremely unlikely, so from the view of a developer, it is of no concern that two hashes could theoretically be the same.

Because of the properties of the password_hash() function and because it generates a random salt for each password...

1. the chance that the function generates a duplicate is incredible small, even if two users use the same password, the function would generate different hashes
2. one cannot search for the hash anyway, you need another search key like the username, so a duplicate wouldn't be a problem neither.

Comment: Well, it *is* somewhat important that the hash is unique, otherwise you have a hash collision, which means you could login with a password that wasn't actually the original password. It would also decrease the work required to brute force a hash collection if you can share the work between two hashes. – The real answer is that the algorithm is designed so it's *very very* unlikely that a collision ever occurs, which is why in practice you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @deceze - Yes that's what I meant with incredible small, and because the answer is related to the `password_hash()` function this is of no concern to the developer. But you are correct, it is formulated unfortunate and should be edited, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

No, it does not check for uniqueness.