# Can password_hash create the same hash in different times with the same parameters?

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I PRETEND TO GENERATE UNIQUE RANDOM VALUE.

Hello I been checking the functionality of password_hash and I need to know if it's possible to generate the same result if you use the same parameters.

For example:

password_hash('12345678',PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 13]) -> $2y$13$8grJKASTBm87TU56QRGbTe7m4FHqis9xVYxBJ.1YL./EgOvu0TPvG

If I repeat this operation "n" times, is possible to replicate the same result? or will always change the value.

If it's impossible to be sure that will always be different, could this modification (adding time()) fix the problem getting always different values?

password_hash('12345678'.time(),PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 13]);

All theses questions was to try to get an easy way to get an unique "token" without using the typical system (if this value exist in bbdd generate another) avoiding to query too much times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Does password\_hash() check if the hash generated is unique? (Understanding!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453650/php-does-password-hash-check-if-the-hash-generated-is-unique-understanding)

Comment: Don't add your own salt to your own password. You're not a cryptography expert.

Comment: All theses questions was to try to get an easy way to get an unique "token" without using the typical system (if this value exist in bbdd generate another) avoiding to query too much times. So how you will do that avoiding to check anytime I generate a random value if already exist in the table that contains all this values.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. The thing that you think makes password hashes unique is just a random value. You can simply get a random value directly without going through password hashing. Also, there are algorithms specifically for this problem, namely [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: *"So how you will do that avoiding to check anytime I generate a random value if already exist in the table that contains all this values."* - if it absolutely, positively (AK47, accept no substitutes) has to be unique *then* I'd put a `UNIQUE` index on the column in the database table and only generate a new UUID when insertion fails because of it (which is basically going to be never).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`password_hash` will add a *random salt value*. Unique salt values will result in unique hashes with a *very very high probability*. The random salt will be taken from the best random number generator available on the system, so the probability of it being unique is *very very high*.

No, there is no **guarantee** that the salt will be unique, or that the hash will be unique. But it is **extremely improbable** for you to find a duplicate ever, unless you're generating billions of hashes every second.

If you're just interested in a *unique token*, just get a random number instead of abusing password hashing functions for something they weren't designed for. Preferably use [`random_bytes`](http://php.net/random_bytes) for this.

Comment: bin2hex(random_bytes(40) or bin2hex(random_bytes(40).time()... But... Can i be sure that inside the table there's not theses values there?

Comment: What do you want `time()` for?! It's *much less random* than any random value.

Comment: Again, you're dealing with *probabilities* here. A long enough value from a good random number generator is ***extremely unlikely*** to ever be duplicated. That is sufficient for regular use. If you need more of a guarantee than *"practically impossible to find a duplicate"*, then you'll need to store the values in a database with a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: Well I will repeat again... it seems people doesn't listen... I want to avoid to check in the table inside bbdd where contains all these randoms uniques values. So I can generate a value completely unique. I though the number of seconds will help. And also I understood that password_hash is not adecuated for the functionality i want. So... do you know any way to generate this "id" but with the appearance from a radom value?

Comment: Oks... now so there is no solution. cheers i will do it by ddbb as always.

Comment: How to put this… There is no way that anyone can honestly say that it's *impossible* to generate two identical random values. ***But*** practically speaking **using `random_bytes` is perfectly fine!** Or as I pointed out above, UUIDs. Many many people rely on random values to be unique, and they are. You just need to get comfortable with the idea of *probabilities*. No, you probably don't have such a unique case that you'll have to store the ids in a database to *guarantee* that they're unique.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `password_hash` uses a random 128-bit salt. So yes, if you repeat this operation 340,282,366,920,938,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 times, you will definitely start to see repeated results. Realistically, this isn't something you need to worry about (even considering the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

Adding `time()` to the initial value is not a sensible idea. Unless you also recorded the time used for each hash, you wouldn't ever be able to reliably recreate the input, which would defeat the point of hashing it.